# Thymeleaf - don't render fragment if file doesn't exist

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf in a Spring Boot application. I want to conditionally include a fragment if the template file exists.

This application will display information about a particular object. Depending on an attribute of that object, I want to include additional information via a fragment. The fragment file name matches the attribute name. I don't control the underlying database, so there could be new attribute names in the future, and I don't want the application to fail when this happens (a different process would determine if a new fragment file is necessary). As a result, I'd like to *not* include the fragment if the template file does not exist.

For example, let's say the object is a `vehicle`, and the attribute is `type`. The type name could be "sports_car", and then I would have a file called `templates/fragments/sports_car.html` that has additional information to display because the `vehicle` is a sports car. Once the application is running a new `type` is created for a "truck", which doesn't have a `truck.html`, and I'd like the application to ignore the related `th:replace`.

I would like to use the following type of code, where

```
<div th:replace="'fragments/'+${type}"></div>
```

And in practice this would evaluate to:

```
# sports_car.html file exists, and is properly rendered
<div th:replace="'fragments/sports_car'"></div>

# File does not exist, nothing is rendered
<div th:replace="'fragments/truck'"></div>
```

Is there any way to ask Thymeleaf is the file exists before trying to render? Thanks.

**Update**

If there isn't an official Thymeleaf way to handle this I'll simply check for the existence of the file in the application, and pass it in as a variable. For example:

```
applicationContext
     .getResource("classpath:templates/fragments/"+type+".html")
     .exists();
```